# Why is socket.io creating a second 'sid' cookie with a different path?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, socket.io

I'm pulling up a project for which I swear this was not a problem before, but apparently is not right now -- I'm probably doing something stupid.  I'm seeing express & socket.io create two different "sid" cookies, one with a path of "/" and the other with a path of "/socket.io".  The behavior I'm expecting is to share the same cookie/session between my express app & socket.io.

**"sid" cookie for "/":**
[image: "sid" for "/"]

**"sid" cookie for "/socket.io":**
[image: "sid" for "/socket.io"]

I'm setting up express via:

```
var config = require('config');
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var sessionStore = require('./session-store');

var sessionConfig = {
  store             : sessionStore,
  secret            : config.server.sessionSecret,
  key               : config.server.sessionKey,
  saveUninitialized : true,
  resave            : true,
  cookie            : { secure: config.server.useHTTPS }
};

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(cookieParser(config.server.sessionSecret));
  app.use(session(sessionConfig));
};
```

I'm setting up socket.io via:

```
var config = require('config');
var redis = require('socket.io-redis')(config.redis.socket);
var cookieParser = require('socket.io-cookie-parser');
var sessionStore = require('./session-store');

module.exports = function (io) {
  io.adapter(redis);

  io.use(cookieParser(config.server.sessionSecret));
  io.use(authorization);
};

function authorization (socket, next) {
  var unauthorized = new Error('Unauthorized');

  if (!socket.request.headers.cookie) {
    return next(unauthorized);
  }

  var sessionKey = socket.server.engine.cookie;
  var sessionId = socket.request.signedCookies[sessionKey] || socket.request.cookies[sessionKey];

  if (!sessionId) {
    return next(unauthorized);
  }

  sessionStore.get(sessionId, function (err, session) {
    // use session's userId to fetch user & attach to socket
  });
}
```

These two files are tied together from my main server file:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var config = require('config');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketio(server, {
  cookie: config.server.sessionKey
});

// initialize aspects of the app
require('./config/initializers/io')(io);
require('./config/initializers/express')(app);

module.exports = server;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think I solved it.  It looks like supplying the `cookie` option when mounting socket.io atop my server ends up causing engine.io to set a cookie with the same name based upon [these lines of code](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/blob/4cc7936688fc14fbe3c420f65b2f90e3198eae57/lib/server.js#L246):

```
if (false !== this.cookie) {
  transport.on('headers', function(headers){
    headers['Set-Cookie'] = self.cookie + '=' + id;
  });
}
```

According to [RFC-2109 HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), the default path is the current URL path:

> ```
> Path   Defaults to the path of the request URL that generated the
>        Set-Cookie response, up to, but not including, the
>        right-most /.
> ```

That would explain the new cookie being created since socket.io's endpoint is `/socket.io` by default.  Since I'm using custom authorization that reads a cookie anyway, I figure it's safe to disable cookies in engine.io by changing my socket instantiation to the following:

```
var io = socketio(server, {
  cookie: false
});
```

This now breaks my `authorization` function included in the original question, specifically this line:

```
var sessionKey = socket.server.engine.cookie;
```

Since I'm no longer passing the cookie key through to socket.io/engine.io, I instead need to read straight from my config:

```
var sessionKey = config.server.sessionKey;
```